# issue with nested @each and nested lists

Tags: sass

I am trying to build a personal CSS-Framework, and I am having trouble using nested @each on nested lists.

I have tried setting up my lists in multiple ways, including maps.  I have tried @for and @each.  What I am doing currently works, but I am just looking to dry it up.  I don't mind what method I use.  I just hate how repetitive the code is.

example list (I have about ten of these):

```
$gray0: rgb(18, 18, 18);
$gray1: rgb(36, 36, 36);
$gray2: rgb(54, 54, 54);
$gray3: rgb(72, 72, 72);
$gray4: rgb(90, 90, 90);
$gray5: rgb(108, 108, 108);
$gray6: rgb(126, 126, 126);
$gray7: rgb(144, 144, 144);
$gray8: rgb(162, 162, 162);
$gray9: rgb(180, 180, 180);
$gray10: rgb(198, 198, 198);
$gray11: rgb(216, 216, 216);
$gray12: rgb(234, 234, 234);

$grays: $gray0, $gray1, $gray2, $gray3, $gray4, $gray5, $gray6, $gray7, $gray8, $gray9, $gray10, $gray11, $gray12;
```

example working loop

```
@each $hue in $grays {
  $i: index($grays, $hue) - 1;
  .text-gray-#{$i} {
    color: $hue;
  }

  .background-gray-#{$i} {
    background-color: $hue;
  }
}
```

Example of something that I tried

```
$colors: $grays, $reds, $greens, $blues, $yellows, $oranges, $purples, $aquas,
  $pinks, $skyBlues;

@each $color in $colors {
  @each $hue in $color {
    $i: index($color, $hue) -1;
    .text-#{$hue}-#{i} {
      color: $hue;
    }
    .background-#{$hue}-#{i} {
      background-color: $hue;
    }
  }
}
```

What I wanted:

```
text-gray-0{
 color: colorHere
}
background-gray-0{
 background-color: colorHere
}
...
text-gray-12{
 color: colorHere
}
background-gray-12: colorHere
}

text-red-0{
 color: colorHere
}
background-red-0{
 background-color: colorHere
}
...
text-red-12{
 color: colorHere
}
background-red-12: colorHere
}

...
```

What I got:

```
.text-#121212-i {
  color: #121212; }

.background-#121212-i {
  background-color: #121212; }
...
.text-#eaeaea-i {
  color: #eaeaea; }

.background-#eaeaea-i {
  background-color: #eaeaea; }

.text-#490000-i {
  color: #490000; }

.background-#490000-i {
  background-color: #490000; }
...
.text-#ff6464-i {
  color: #ff6464; }

.background-#ff6464-i {
  background-color: #ff6464; }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your are trying to use a variable name as a string. Even if it was possible (which is not), with your current code you would end up with class like `.text-gray0-0`.

What you need to use is a map of your colors:

```
$colors: (
  gray: $grays,
  red: $reds,
  ...
);
```

And then you can do:

```
@each $color, $hues in $colors {
  @each $hue in $hues {
    $i: index($hues, $hue) - 1;

    .text-#{$color}-#{$i} {
      color: $hue;
    }

    .background-#{$color}-#{$i} {
      background-color: $hue;
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of declaring each hue in a separate variable, you also have the option to use a map with the indexes as keys such as:

```
$grays: (
  0: rgb(18, 18, 18),
  1: rgb(36, 36, 36),
  ...
);
```

Then you can remove `$i: index($hues, $hue) - 1;` and use this:

```
@each $color, $hues in $colors {
  @each $index, $hue in $hues {
    .text-#{$color}-#{$index} {
       color: $hue;
     }

    .background-#{$color}-#{$index} {
       background-color: $hue;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked! (the first solution).  Would the second way be preferred?

Comment: Both are okay, it's up to you to use the one you prefer. :)